# i'm getting error if i give && condition in simpleTogglePanel opened. can anyone correct me

Tags: richfaces

i'm getting error if i give && condition in opened. can anyone correct me.

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel label="Search Criteria" id="searchToggle"
            opened="#{viewScope.searchAction.soSCPanel && viewScope.resetAction.soSCpanel}" switchType="client"
            style="text-align:left; width:955px;*width:955px">
```

I'm getting below Errors, I tried with "and"operator but in that case both conditions is not working properly.

com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /jsp/mass/ship/search.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:234)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:293)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Can you put and condition like this

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel label="Search Criteria" id="searchToggle"
        opened="#{viewScope.searchAction.soSCPanel and viewScope.resetAction.soSCpanel}" switchType="client"
        style="text-align:left; width:955px;*width:955px">
```

So, the changes would be 'and' instead of '&&' it seems like the logical && and || will not be interpreted by jsf EL(expression language).

check out this link will be useful :)

https://community.jboss.org/thread/187242